# Mysql table record is not getting updated using Update query

Tags: jquery, mysql, jsp

I have two tables in my database(Database Name:dmsqms) i.e. dmsmembers and dmsfiles. For dmsmembers "zid" is primary key and for dmsfiles "document_name" is primary key. "zid" column is same for both tables. When user do registration then record stores into dmsmembers. When user save form (index.jsp) then this record saves into dmsfiles table. I also have one filelist.jsp where all records are fetched from database using "**select * from dmsfiles**" query. In filelist.jsp, for each record/row there is one **Edit** button. When user clicks on "Edit" then respective jsp form opens then user do changes as per need and clicks on "Update" button. Now problem is when user clicks on Update button then it redirects to next page but record is not getting updated. From my point, there may be problem of primary key.

**filelistJSP.jsp**

```html
<body>
<br>
<center><h3><i>Note: Here you can see all files uploaded by you only.</i></h3></center>
<br>
<br>
<center>
<%
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
%>
<table border="2">
  <tr>
   <th style="width: 20%">Z ID</th>
   <th style="width: 20%">First Name</th>
   <th style="width: 20%">Last Name</th>
   <th style="width: 20%">Mail ID</th>
   ...
   <th class="text-center">Edit Form</th>
   </tr>
<%
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root","");
   String zid = request.getParameter("zid");
   String sql = "select * from dmsfiles where zid= '"+zid+"'";
   ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs = ps.executeQuery();
   while(rs.next()){
    %>
   <tr>
   <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>              
   <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>           
   <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>   
   <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td> 
   <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td> 
   <td><%=rs.getString(6)%></td> 
   <td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
   <td><%=rs.getString(8)%></td>              
   ...
   <td><%=rs.getString(24)%></td>
   <td><a href="DownloadServletClass?fileName=<%=rs.getString(22)%>" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a></td>
   <td><a href="editnew.jsp?zid=<%=rs.getString("zid")%>&documentname=<%=rs.getString(9)%>" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
 </tr>
<%
   }
%>    
</table><br>
<a href="home.jsp" class="btn btn-info">Home</a>
</center>
</body>
```

**editnew.jsp**

```html
<body>
<br>
<div id="Registercontainer">
<div class="RegForm">    
<div id="back_glob">    
<div id="back_form">
<%
  try{
    String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms";
    Statement stat = null;
    ResultSet res = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,"root","");
 %>
 <form action="editprocess.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <%
      stat = conn.createStatement();
      String docName = request.getParameter("documentname");
      String zid = request.getParameter("zid");
      String data = "select * from dmsfiles where zid = '"+zid+"' AND document_name = '"+docName+"'";
      res = stat.executeQuery(data);
      while(res.next()){
     %>
     
     <center><h2>Edit form</h2></center>
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=res.getString("zid") %>">
      <table width="400px" align="center" border="2">
       <tr>
         <td align="center" colspan="2">Form Details</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Z id</td>
       <td>
       <input type="text" name="zid" value='<%=res.getString(1)%>'/>
       </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>First Name</td>
       <td>
       <input type="text" required="" name="firstname" value='<%=res.getString(2)%>'/>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" required="" name="lastname" value='<%=res.getString(3)%>'/>
        </td>
        </tr>
        
        ...
        
        <%
          }
        %>    
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="update" name="update"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        <br>
        <center><a href="home.jsp" class="btn btn-info">Home</a></center>
    </div>
    </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
    <%
        }  //try block close
        catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println(e);
        }   
%>
</body>
```

**editprocess.jsp**

```html
<body>
<%
String z_id = request.getParameter("zid");
String first_Name = request.getParameter("firstname");
String last_Name = request.getParameter("lastname");
String mail_i_d = request.getParameter("mailid");
String d_iv = request.getParameter("division");

...

String iss_uer = request.getParameter("issuer");
String sta_tus = request.getParameter("status");
String file_Name = "";
String folder_Name = "allfiles";
String pa_th = folder_Name + File.separator + file_Name;
Timestamp add_ed_date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()); 

if(request.getParameter("update") != null){
   // out.println("in");
   Connection con = null;
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
                
   try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root","");
     String sql = "update dmsfiles set firstname=?,lastname=?,mailid=?,division=?,department=?,costcentercode=?,document_number=?,document_type=?,document_category=?,document_classification=?,authorised_by=?,fromdate=?,todate=?,document_level=?,document_general=?,serial_number=?,revision_number=?,issuer=?,status=?,filename=?,path=?,added_date=? where document_name='"+doc_Name+"'"; 
      ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      // ps.setString(1,z_id);
      ps.setString(1,first_Name);
      ps.setString(2,last_Name);
      ps.setString(3,mail_i_d);
      ps.setString(4,d_iv);
      ps.setString(5,de_pt);
      
      ...
       
      ps.setString(19,iss_uer);
      ps.setString(20,sta_tus);
      ps.setString(21,file_Name);
      ps.setString(22,pa_th);
      ps.setTimestamp(23, add_ed_date);
      int i = ps.executeUpdate();
      con.commit();
      if(i > 0)
      {
       out.println("alert('Record Updated Successfully');");
      }
      else
      {
       out.println("alert('There is a problem in updating Record.');");
      }
      }
      catch(SQLException sql)
      {
        sql.printStackTrace();
      }
      }
%>
<a href="home.jsp" class="btn btn-info">Home</a>
</body>
```

**Exception Occurred:**

```html
20-Feb-2020 11:12:43.827 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/DMS2] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /searchResult.jsp at line 97

94:<td align="center"><c:out value="${row.added_date}"/></td>
95:                            
96:<td align="center"><a href="DownloadServletClass?fileName=${row.fileName}" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a></td>
97:<td align="center"><a href="editnew.jsp?zid=<%=rs.getString("zid")%>&documentname=<%=rs.getString(9)%>" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
98:                            
99: 
100: 


Stacktrace:] with root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.jsp.searchResult_jsp._jspService(searchResult_jsp.java:371)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**searchResult.jsp**

```html
<form name="empForm" method="post">
<div>
<table border="2" style="width:100%" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="3">
 <tr>
  <th>Z ID</th>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Mail ID</th>
  <th>Division</th>
  <th>Department</th>
  <th>Cost Center Code</th>
  <th>Document No.</th>
  <th>Document Name</th>
  <th>Document Type</th>
  <th>Document Category</th>
  ...                      
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>File Name</th>
  <th>Added Date</th>
  <th>Download</th>
  <th>Edit Form</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
<%
   Connection con = null;
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
 %>
 <sql:query var="empData" dataSource="${emp}">
   SELECT * FROM dmsfiles emp where 
   emp.document_number like '%<%=request.getParameter("documentnumber")%>%' and
   emp.document_name like '%<%=request.getParameter("documentname")%>%' and
   emp.document_type like '%<%=request.getParameter("Document_Type")%>%' and
   emp.document_category like '%<%=request.getParameter("Document_Category")%>%' and
   emp.document_classification like '%<%=request.getParameter("Document_Classification")%>%'
</sql:query>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${empData.rows}">
  <tr>
   <td align="center"><c:out value="${row.zid}"/></td>
   <td align="center"><c:out value="${row.firstname}"/></td>
   <td align="center"><c:out value="${row.lastname}"/></td>
   <td align="center"><c:out value="${row.mailid}"/></td>
   <td align="center"><c:out value="${row.division}"/></td>
   ...
   <td align="center"><c:out value="${row.revision_number}"/></td>
   <td align="center"><c:out value="${row.issuer}"/></td>
   <td align="center"><c:out value="${row.status}"/></td>
   <td align="center"><c:out value="${row.fileName}"/></td>
   <td align="center"><c:out value="${row.added_date}"/></td>
   <td align="center"><a href="DownloadServletClass?fileName=${row.fileName}" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a></td>
   <td align="center"><a href="editnew.jsp?zid=${row.zid}&document_name=${row.document_name}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
   </tr>
   </c:forEach>
   </tbody>
   </table>  
   </div>    
</form>
```

Comment: someone please help me with this problem I am trying since two weeks but I didn't got solution :(

Comment: **Welcome**.  If you notice, this post had been viewed 17 times but to get what you want, please be more specific. Remove all unwanted (as per your problem). Make a minimal reproducable model with data structure. Several are willing to answer. In addition, you shall insert additional code to print in-between your process to check what is happening.

Comment: OK, you have `sql.printStackTrace();` in the `catch` clause, is there any exception in the log? Btw. never EVER use string concatenation to create SQL commands from user input (`"select * from dmsfiles where zid= '"+zid+"'"`), not even in a school project. This makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Comment: And a second remark: such code (loading from DB, updating the DB) does not belong to JSP, learn to use [Model-View-Controller](https://www.baeldung.com/mvc-servlet-jsp) pattern. Would be easier to debug, too.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek As you said to use PreparedStatement instead of SQL Injection. I did changes. There are no exceptions. I want to edit particular record. So when I click on Edit button for respective row then index.jsp form opens with previous stored values and then I did some changes and clicked on update button then it redirects to next page but no changes done in database. I am not getting why??

Comment: @NatarajanNNapoleon Please tell me what more information do you need?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Give data structure, sample data, etc and continue. One doubt is that the where clause might have returned false wherein catch will not have any error.

Comment: I assume that the update script got `WHERE document_name='"+doc_Name+"'";` as `undefined`. Are you able to catch the `doc_name` value by deliberately changing the table name in your `UPDATE` to non-existing table and see the whole query when it returns error `Table not found`? Maybe change your `UPDATE dmsfiles ...` to `UPDATE *any non-existing table name ..` then try click update.

Comment: @tcadidot0 no error occurred. I did changes as you said but no error and no update. Could you please tell me that is it necessary to have same primary key for both tables to update record??  because I have two different primary keys for both tables and on that table I am performing Update query.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek could you please check above exception that is occurred? I have added exception in question. Please check.

Comment: Well, obviously, `rs` is `null` at that point. We need to see hte code of `searchResult.jsp` to tell more. Is it the same as `filelistJSP.jsp` you have in your question?

Comment: both are different. searchResult.jsp is to display searched data.

Comment: The code from stack trace `97:<td align="center"><a href="editnew.jsp?zid=<%=rs.getString("zid")%>&documentname=<%=rs.getString(9)%>" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>` and the code you've posted `<td align="center"><a href="editnew.jsp?zid=${row.zid}&document_name=${row.document_name}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>` differ, the code you've posted should work.

Comment: @priyadhanba In your `editnew.jsp` ,how you are passing `doc_Name` to `editprocess.jsp`? because there is no `inputs` for this under your `form` ?